# When iterating a list of lists, why does calling List.clear on the iterator remove the list from the parent list?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, apache-commons

Why does calling clear on the iterator here shorten the size of the batches array?

```
ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"));
    List<List<String>> numberBatches = ListUtils.partition(numbers, 2);
    for(List<String> numberBatch : numberBatches) {
        for(String number : numberBatch) {
            System.out.println(number);
        }
        numberBatch.clear();
    }
```

**Output**

```
1
2
5
6
9
10
```

Comment: Which `ListUtils` is your `ListUtils`? Note that you are not calling "clear on the iterator", you are calling _clear on a list reference_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListUtils.partition(numbers, 2)` gives you *view* of the original list. The `List<List<T>>` is constructed using the method [`List#subList(fromIndex, toIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-). This method returns a view of the original list.

Calling `clear` on a subList will remove the items from the original, underlying list.

So when the loop starts the next iteration, it will continue at the index where it left off. But the values at this index have shifted already. That's why you see missing numbers in your sequence.

It is generally discouraged to modify the collection which you are iterating.

Comment: In the case where the initial list is very larger and processing items leads to memory exhaustion, how can modifying the collection during iteration be avoided?

Comment: @Half_Duplex why do you need to partition? If you iterate the original list, the iterator should be still in sync.

Comment: In this case, the partitions are being added to a Mongo bulk update operation. Adding the full list to the bulk operation, or updating the records individually is not feasible.

Comment: @Half_Duplex do you really have n/2 sublists? If your partition size is larger, you can copy the _references_ of the partitions to a new list. This list will only hold references, not the full list contents.

Answer (score 3):

Per [ListUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html#partition-java.util.List-int-) documentation:

> The outer list is unmodifiable, but reflects the latest state of the source list. **The inner lists are sublist views of the original list, produced on demand using List.subList(int, int)**, and are subject to all the usual caveats about modification as explained in that API.

In essence, the inner list objects keep a reference to the *index* of the items in the original list. When you call `List#clear`, you are really removing the items from the original `numbers` list. However, without the other sublists updating their indices, you end up "skipping over" the remaining items:

```
Output    Index     numbers List
1         0         [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
2         1         [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
5         2         [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
6         3         [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
9         4         [3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10]
10        5         [3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

This should probably be a candidate for throwing a `ConcurrentModificationException`, though the documentation does essentially warn against modifying the sublists while iterating.